# EMC BIOS default password

Tags: password, bios, emc, celerra

I have an EMC server that hasn't been used for a while and I am trying to repurpose it. I am having trouble getting into the BIOS as it seems to be locked behind a password by default.

Hardware:
EMC server, not sure what type, I can't see any markings on it.
Server Board: S1200BTL

What I did:
Tried resetting the motherboard to default by:

- taking out CMOS battery
- taking out all the jumpers one by one.

Passwords I have tried:

- emcbios
- abc123
- 123456
- empty

Entering an empty password lets me see the BIOS settings, but they are all greyed out (read only mode).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go back to your documentation.

Comment: Clearing BIOS passwords is generally done by moving a specific jumper from one position to another. The specific jumper and appropriate setting is typically marked on the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

My main problem was that I was looking for EMC manuals, as it is an EMC server, but instead I should have been looking at the Intel board manual (S1200BTL):
https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/motherboards/server/sb/g13326007_s1200bt_tps_r2_4.pdf

On page 158 (109 by the manual page numbering) I found an image that explains the jumpers on the board (sorry, im not able to paste it here). One of the jumpers is a password reset jumper. The process I followed was:
1. I changed the jumper to "clear"
2. restarted the machine, and had full access to the BIOS without a need for a password
3. changed admin password -> shut down machine -> changed back the jumper
4. My new password is set and I can now use the machine and access the BIOS

Hopes this helps other people. Thanks to al lthe people who replied to me and put me on the right track, prior to this I didn't kow there was even a concept of a password reset jumper.

Answer (score 0):

I just found it.

If it's default, try EMCBIOS rather than emcbios. I punched my desk so hard after I guessed it, been trying to get the password for weeks.